# how can I load the cookies from diff browsers to asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cookies, browser

I logged in my facebook and saved my username/password (firefox)
and I want to know how can I access it from asp.net?

Comment: Same answer as your last question that was deleted, you can not do it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

Browsers will not send cookies set by a website to a different website, nor will they send the contents of the browser's password vault.

If they did, then every website you visited would be able to steal your login token / credentials for every other website you visited.

Comment: If you *do* ever figure out a way to do this, let the browser vendor know and they will probably give you a pile of money from their bug bounty program.

Comment: do u know where are the passwords have saved in computer?

Comment: No. It varies from platform to platform and browser to browser.

Comment: thnx, imagine we found out the file that my passwords have saved in it, dose the browser encrypt the file? or not?

Comment: @HawreSalimi If you need to ask another unrelated question, then go create a new one. But make sure you put some time into it and try to figure out the answer yourself before asking.

Comment: You can not steal passwords off a computer.